# Add a .net user control in lotus notes

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

Simple Question,

is it possible to add a custom pane in lotus notes inside which we want to add a .net user control?

I want to add a custom pane on the right in lotus notes containing my user control in order to drop items from the lotus notes inbox (emails i received) to my user control.

Is it a complicated  process? (i know in outlook, we can have an add-in in just a few steps).

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no VSTO for Lotus Notes, you check this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lotusnoteintegrator.aspx